# Update status, meta while inside a post using AJAX button

Tags: ajax, post-meta, wp-update-post

So I am trying to click a custom button I made in a meta box the fire off AJAX. All works except getting the ID of the post and the refreshing of the page. I have tried using `global $post; $post_id = $post->ID` or `$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];` or `$post_id = get_the_ID();` , none of these work.

What I was trying to accomplish eventually is: after clicking the button, a popup happens with "are you sure?"Yes/No. If I click Yes, to change Status function fires and refreshes the post page with status changed.

I am using an Ajax Get with the URL of behind my button:
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ew_change_status

Reference: 
[Trying to load content of a post via AJAX](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61565/trying-to-load-content-of-a-post-via-ajax)

This is my functions.php code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_change_status', 'ew_change_status' );


function ew_change_status() {

    //$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    //$post_id = get_the_ID();

    global $post; 
    global $user_ID; 

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    var_dump($post_id);

    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

   //Show popup
   // ...

   // Update Status
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_status'   => 'status-pending',
  );

   // Update custom field with User Id      
   update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_key', $user_ID);

   //echo "Updated";

   // Update the post into the database
   wp_update_post( $my_post );

    //wp_redirect(); //Same Page?
    //exit;

}
```

Comment: If you're making the AJAX request to the `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, the `$post` object is `null` and so does `get_queried_object()`, because there's no queried object - unlike for example, when loading a post page, the queried object is a post. So you might want to *send the post ID from your AJAX script* (JS).

Comment: Well. If I use `admin_notices` action it seems to work somewhat.

Comment: Because `admin_notices` is fired later; but the `wp_ajax_xxx` is fired earlier before the `$post` is setup. Try `var_dump( did_action( 'admin_notices' ) );` from the `wp_ajax_xxx` callback.

Comment: IS there another hook I could use?

Comment: Check my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First things first

In a `wp_ajax_{action}` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` callback, the global `$post` variable is by default a `null` because WordPress has not yet set it up. You can confirm it using a simple callback like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test', function(){
    global $post;
    var_dump( $post );
    wp_die();
} );
```

Visit `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test` and you should see `NULL` displayed on the page. If you don't see a `NULL`, then it's possible that a plugin or custom code has made a query which changed the `$post` variable.

### Now a solution

Since you're making the AJAX request via a button click and the button is inside a meta box which I suppose is on the post edit screen (`wp-admin/edit.php`), then an easy way to fix the issue of the `$post` being still a `NULL` in your `wp_ajax_change_status` callback, is to send the post ID from your AJAX script (JavaScript).

On the post edit screen, the post ID is stored in a hidden `input` field named `post_ID` which looks like this and stores the ID of the post that's currently being edited:

```
<input type='hidden' id='post_ID' name='post_ID' value='123' />
```

So you can use the value and send it to your AJAX callback. E.g.:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action:  'change_status',
        post_id: jQuery( '#post_ID' ).val() // send the post ID
    },
    type: 'post'
});
```

Then in your AJAX callback (i.e. the `ew_change_status()` function), you can retrieve the submitted post ID like so:

```
$post_id = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );
```

### Additional Notes

1. In your AJAX callback, make sure to check whether the current user can edit the post. E.g.:

   ```
   if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
       wp_die();
   }
   ```
2. Use a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) (because you are editing a post). For example,

   a) In your meta box, create a hidden `input` for storing the nonce:

   ```
   // Creates an <input> with the `id` and `name` "my_security".
   <?php wp_nonce_field( 'change-post-status', 'my_security' ); ?>
   ```

   b) Include the nonce in the AJAX request:

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
       data: {
           action:  'change_status',
           post_id:  jQuery( '#post_ID' ).val(),
           security: jQuery( '#my_security' ).val()
       },
       type: 'post'
   });
   ```

   c) In your AJAX callback, verify the nonce:

   ```
   check_ajax_referer( 'change-post-status', 'security' );
   ```

So your `ew_change_status()` may look like:

```
function ew_change_status() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'change-post-status', 'security' );

    $post_id = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );
    if ( ! $post_id || ! ( $post = get_post( $post_id ) ) ) {
        wp_die( 'No such post, or invalid ID.' );
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        wp_die( 'You can not edit this post.' );
    }

    ... your code here ...

    wp_die();
}
```